# Postprocessing FX for a few seconds

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I would like to add an effect on an object or on a specific mesh for a few seconds and then delete the fx again. 
As I am new to three.js I played around with the postprocessing examples on the website. My scene is up an running, gltf model is loaded, handlers for textures and so on are all working as expected. But I am not sure how to add an fx...

The scenario I want to implement is the following;
For each time a user changes a texture on the model, the mesh should fire an fx for a second, so that the user gets a kind of visual feedback that something has changed (besides the change of the texture).

If anyone could point me into the right direction I would be very thankful.

Comment: I think you might have better luck asking this type of open-ended questions in the Three.js forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: hm, ok, sorry for bothering you if this was the wrong place...
And thx for the link !!